# Replace specific value in given text using c#-regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace some value in given text using c# preferably using regex

Input : This is sample text. I need to replace $100.00 value with new value.

Output : This is sample text. I need to replace $50.00 value with new value.

> **need to replace $100 to $50**

Note: The number should be any size

solution:
this works for my requirement

Regex.Replace("This is sample text. I need to replace $100.00 value with new value.", 
"\$\d+(\.\d+)?" , "50", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Comment: and regardless of the size it should always be replaced by "$50"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
RegEx rex = new RegEx("\\$\\d+\\.\\d\\d");
```

Then just use the replace function.

```
rex.Replace(input, "$50.00");
```

If you need to be able to determine the value to replace dynamically, based on the matched number take a look at the [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator).

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for regular expressions if you are looking to replace a constant value:

```
string output = text.Replace("$100", "$50");
```

If you don't know the number in advance you can use regular expressions but you'll need to figure out what pattern you want. Here's an example for matching a dollar sign followed by one or more digits, then a decimal point, then two more digits:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\$\d+\.\d{2}", "$50.00");
```

You will need this `using` statement for the above code to work:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

You should modify the regular expression to suit your needs. You may want to consider the full range of inputs that you need to match:

- Do you need to match a decimal point?
- Do you need to match a comma?
- Do you need to match negative values?
- Do you need to match letters as in "$1M"?
- Do you need to match the currency code instead of the dollar symbol "10 USD"?
- Do you need to match other currencies as in "€100"?
- etc...

Depending on your answers to these questions you will need to adjust the regular expression.

Comment: i don't know the value in middle of the text .. it should be any value

Comment: @PrakashM: Do you know that it will only consist of digits? Could it be something like `$1M`?

Comment: Your regex does not include dot and coma, I think he needs something like this - (\$[\d\.,]+)

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin: What about negative numbers? Your expression doesn't handle that. (And neither does mine, but I'm not going to pretend that I can guess what the OP wants).

Comment: @MarkByers But his example actually does contain a dot:-) `$100.00`

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin: But in his text he says he writes in **bold** that he wants to replace "$100" with "$50". He didn't say he wanted to replace the dot. Don't ask me why! I'm not going to try to *guess* what he wants. I'm going to try to *ask* him.

Comment: i need to replace like $100.00 to $50.00 .. also the values are not constant .. it should be any number in between given text ... also no commas

Comment: @PrakashM: "Like `$100.00`" is a very vague statement. Is `$ 100` like `$100.00`? Is `£100.00` like `$100.00`. Is `$.99` like `$100.00`? Is `$100.000` like `$100.00`? Can you be **more specific**? Give ten examples of things that should match, and twenty examples of things that shouldn't match. Make sure you cover *every* one of the examples I gave you classifying it as either "should match" or "shouldn't match", plus try to think of some more examples of your own. Think of examples that really demonstrate exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: And don't post the examples in the comments. Instead edit and update your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces any value with optional decimal values:

```
Regex.Replace( s, @"\$\d+(\.\d+)?", "$50" )
```